# json.parse function while dealing with large data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the JSON.parse function in Google Scripts. While this works on content which is of small size, the json.parse function fails in the case of large content(The input string has 34997 characters excluding spaces)

[sample log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFKCl.png)

Only a small part of the data gets formatted in JSON. Would like to understand how I can achieve this for the entire data. Please do elaborate as I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Logger.log() will cut off your data, because there's too much for it to display. (Scroll down and you should see a message indicating this.) If `JSON.parse()` were failing, it would have given you an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sometimes links go down, so just to be safe it's better to add the small sample that is specific to your question into your post. You can keep the link, but please put the relevant stuff directly into your question. It's ok if it's a bit long.

Comment: Instead of displaying it in the log, display on a dialog of your own

Answer (score 0):

`Logger.log` will truncate the output after a certain number of characters.

If `JSON.parse` was failing you would be seeing an execution error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to display your data it's quick and simple.

```
 function displayData(s) {
      if(s) {
        var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Display Data")
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I did try using the dialog box but it just gives me the output
[object Object]
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: I don't know, was the parameter `s` a string?